# How to offer variable In-App Purchase prices like this developer is doing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I read in [this article](http://www.imore.com/game-developer-offer-iap-permanent-unlock-option) about a developer who has an "all you can eat" pack of In App Purchases. The price of this pack varies depending on how much other IAP you bought before buying the pack. So it compensates the user when they already spent money for individual items and then decide to get the flatrate all you can eat pack.

How is this done technically? I can't see how Apple would let an app decide the price for an in-app purchase item. Only explanation is that they created many in-app purchase items for the same pack with different prices. Is this how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple products which are the same, but with different ifentifiers and prices. Then, when you display your store you simply look at the record of purchases in the app and decide which one of your products to display.